# Send Action on rotation of device iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, action

here is what I'm trying to achieve, it would be to send an action on rotation of the device...

the point is i'm having a 360 player, I would like the video to start only once the device is on landscape. If it's in portrait i'd like to display a message a saying "rotate your device in landscape to start", and when the user rotate the device, the video play.

below is my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation ]== UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo1" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        Video360ViewController *videoController = [[Video360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTY360PlayerVC" bundle:nil url:url];

        [videoController VRMode:true];

        if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
            [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
}
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
{
    NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationPortrait");
}

}
```

The problem of this code is than it trigger only on TouchUp Inside in the Sent Event . .  . anyway to have the action starting on rotation ?

Thanks for all your help !

EDIT---

TRYIED THE FOLLOWING ASWELL:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation ]== UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo1" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        Video360ViewController *videoController = [[Video360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTY360PlayerVC" bundle:nil url:url];

        [videoController VRMode:true];

        if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
            [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
}
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
{
    NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationPortrait");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

Comment: WHere should I add this ? under the first line of IBAction ?

Comment: include this method in ur class

Comment: Hm, Im not sur to understand, Im just starting in iOS Dev. I've edit the question with adding the code you said but it show me an error " USe on undercalred identifier shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation'

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help, really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Try put your code inside:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

}
```

and write this methods in your `UIViewController`. This method is called when the device (interface really) is rotated; if you want do something before the rotation of interface, use `willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`